# CoreDNS fails to run in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, coredns

I'm trying to setup a Kubernetes cluster, but I cannot get CoreDNS running. I've ran the following to start the cluster:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
sudo kubeadm init

mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s- version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

To check the PODs with `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`, I get

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-68fb79bcf6-6s5bp                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          10m
kube-system   coredns-68fb79bcf6-hckxq                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          10m
kube-system   etcd-myserver                           1/1     Running            0          79m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-myserver                 1/1     Running            0          79m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-myserver        1/1     Running            0          79m
kube-system   kube-proxy-9ls64                        1/1     Running            0          80m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-myserver                 1/1     Running            0          79m
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-tqt8m   1/1     Running            0          80m
kube-system   weave-net-zmhwg                         2/2     Running            0          80m
```

So CoreDNS keeps crashing. The only error messages I could found were from
`/var/log/syslog`:

```
Oct  4 18:06:44 myserver kubelet[16397]: E1004 18:06:44.961409   16397 pod_workers.go:186] Error syncing pod c456a48b-c7c3-11e8-bf23-02426706c77f ("coredns-68fb79bcf6-6s5bp_kube-system(c456a48b-c7c3-11e8-bf23-02426706c77f)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "coredns" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=coredns pod=coredns-68fb79bcf6-6s5bp_kube-system(c456a48b-c7c3-11e8-bf23-02426706c77f)"
```

and from `kubectl logs coredns-68fb79bcf6-6s5bp -n kube-system`:

```
.:53
2018/10/04 11:04:55 [INFO] CoreDNS-1.2.2
2018/10/04 11:04:55 [INFO] linux/amd64, go1.11, eb51e8b
CoreDNS-1.2.2
linux/amd64, go1.11, eb51e8b
2018/10/04 11:04:55 [INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = f65c4821c8a9b7b5eb30fa4fbc167769
2018/10/04 11:04:55 [FATAL] plugin/loop: Seen "HINFO IN 3256902131464476443.1309143030470211725." more than twice, loop detected
```

Some solutions I found are to issue

```
kubectl -n kube-system get deployment coredns -o yaml | \
sed 's/allowPrivilegeEscalation: false/allowPrivilegeEscalation: true/g' | \
kubectl apply -f -
```

and to modify `/etc/resolv.conf` to point to an actual DNS, not to localhost, which I tried as well.

The issue is described in https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#pods-in-runcontainererror-crashloopbackoff-or-error-state and I tried many different Pod Networks but no help.

I've run `sudo kubeadm reset && rm -rf ~/.kube/ && sudo kubeadm init` several times.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, Kubernetes 1.12 and Docker 17.03. Any ideas?

Comment: Turns out it was the problem from creating a loop when the nameserver in resolv.conf pointed to localhost and systemd-resolved was running. So I stopped the service and manually added nameservers through Ubuntu's network settings. Instead of this, I wanted to specify the location of resolv.conf for CoreDNS, but I could not figure out how to do this. I tried to specify the location through a config file with `kubeadm init --config config.yaml` but kubelet/CoreDNS didn't pick up the file. I'd be still interested how to specify alternative location of resolv.conf to kubeadm.

Comment: Just a follow up, for those who are still having this error. coredns:1.2.6 does not have this problem, without any additional config. So, the easist way to fix it, is to upgrade coredns to 1.2.6 using this command: `kubectl patch deployment -n=kube-system coredns -p '{"spec": {"template": {"spec":{"containers":[{"image":"k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.2.6", "name":"coredns","resources":{"limits":{"memory":"1Gi"},"requests":{"cpu":"100m","memory":"70Mi"}}}]}}}}'`

Comment: @RichardLi Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 25):

I also have the same issue.

I've solved the problem by deleting the plugins 'loop' within the cm of coredns.
but i don't know if this cloud case other porblems.

1、kubectl edit cm coredns -n kube-system

2、[delete ‘loop’ ,save and exit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsYL1.png)

3、restart coredns pods by：`kubectl delete pod coredns.... -n kube-system`

Comment: This worked for me, but do we know why it works?  Are we loosing anything by removing it?

Comment: From https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#known-issues :Some Linux distributions (e.g. Ubuntu), use a local DNS resolver by default (systemd-resolved). Systemd-resolved moves and replaces /etc/resolv.conf with a stub file that can cause a fatal forwarding loop when resolving names in upstream servers. This can be fixed manually by using kubelet’s --resolv-conf flag to point to the correct resolv.conf (With systemd-resolved, this is /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf)

Comment: Use KUBE_EDITOR="nano" before kubectl edit .... to edit within nano instead of vim

Comment: I tried this and CPU utilization from coredns was very high. Removing `loop` means coredns will have no way to detect dns resolution loops. Removing `loop` isn't recommended.

Answer (score 10):

Somewhat resolved by using this way:

1. open and edit the configmap of coredns.

   > `kubectl edit cm coredns -n kube-system`
2. "replacing proxy . /etc/resolv.conf with the ip address of your upstream DNS, for example proxy . 8.8.8.8." According to [the link in the output of
   the coredns log](https://coredns.io/plugins/loop/#troubleshooting) (at the end of the page)
3. save and exit.
4. > kubectl get pods -n kube-system -oname |grep coredns |xargs kubectl delete -n kube-system

The reason of the problem is explained in the [link](https://coredns.io/plugins/loop/#troubleshooting).
You can find this link in the output of this cmd

> kubectl logs coredns-7d9cd4f75b-cpwxp -n kube-system

This link is in the output of the CoreDNS-1.2.4.

I upgrade the CoreDNS using this cmd

> kubectl patch deployment -n=kube-system coredns -p '{"spec": {"template": {"spec":{"containers":[{"image":"k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.2.4", "name":"coredns","resources":{"limits":{"memory":"1Gi"},"requests":{"cpu":"100m","memory":"70Mi"}}}]}}}}'

Comment: This fix worked for me. Though  `proxy . /etc/resolv.conf` was absent on my config map. I added `forward . 8.8.8.8` and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

I think simply delete `loop` function from Kubernetes is not a clean approach. [CoreDNS Github](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/blob/master/plugin/loop/README.md) actually provides some guidelines for trouble shooting this issue.

They suggest in their guideline about 3 approaches

> - Add the following to kubelet: --resolv-conf . Your "real" resolv.conf is the one that contains the actual IPs of your upstream servers, and no local/loopback address. This flag tells kubelet to pass an alternate resolv.conf to Pods. For systems using systemd-resolved, /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf is typically the location of the "real" resolv.conf, although this can be different depending on your distribution.
> - Disable the local DNS cache on host nodes, and restore /etc/resolv.conf to the original.
> - A quick and dirty fix is to edit your Corefile, replacing proxy . /etc/resolv.conf with the ip address of your upstream DNS, for example proxy . 8.8.8.8. But this only fixes the issue for CoreDNS, kubelet will continue to forward the invalid resolv.conf to all default dnsPolicy Pods, leaving them unable to resolve DNS.

Comment: As of the above workaround to cleanly update `/etc/resolv.conf` on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I deleted `coredns` pod. Then fixed this issue of CrashLoopBackOff

`kubectl delete pod -n=kube-system coredns-fb8b8dccf-8ggcf`

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to delete `--network-plugin=cni` in `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env`

Comment: after removing the `--network-plugin=cni` from `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadmflags.env` still shows runing pods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. The issue was described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#pods-in-runcontainererror-crashloopbackoff-or-error-state) and [on GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/998). And the resolution is to upgrade Docker, disable SElinux or modify `allowPrivilegeEscalation` to `true`.
However, today I have tried to reproduce your issue and wasn't able to do this.
Providing you commands and output, maybe it will help you create a working version from the beginning.

> Docker version 17.03.2-ce, Kubernetes v1.12.0, Ubuntu 16.04, CoreDNS-1.2.2, instance created in GCP.

```
#apt-get update && apt-get install -y mc ebtables ethtool docker.io apt-transport-https curl
#curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -

#cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list \
deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main \
EOF

#apt-get update && apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl

#kubeadm init
$mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
$sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
$sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
$kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
```

> serviceaccount/weave-net created
>
> clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/weave-net created
>
> clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/weave-net created
>
> role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/weave-net created
>
> rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/weave-net created
>
> daemonset.extensions/weave-net created

```
$kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                              READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   pod/coredns-576cbf47c7-6qbtq                      0/1     Pending             0          79s
kube-system   pod/coredns-576cbf47c7-jr6hb                      0/1     Pending             0          79s
kube-system   pod/etcd-kube-weave-master-1                      1/1     Running             0          38s
kube-system   pod/kube-apiserver-kube-weave-master-1            1/1     Running             0          28s
kube-system   pod/kube-controller-manager-kube-weave-master-1   1/1     Running             0          30s
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-4p9l5                              1/1     Running             0          79s
kube-system   pod/kube-scheduler-kube-weave-master-1            1/1     Running             0          34s
kube-system   pod/weave-net-z6mhw                               0/2     ContainerCreating   0          8s
```

And again in a minute:

```
$kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   pod/coredns-576cbf47c7-6qbtq                      1/1     Running   0          98s
kube-system   pod/coredns-576cbf47c7-jr6hb                      1/1     Running   0          98s
kube-system   pod/etcd-kube-weave-master-1                      1/1     Running   0          57s
kube-system   pod/kube-apiserver-kube-weave-master-1            1/1     Running   0          47s
kube-system   pod/kube-controller-manager-kube-weave-master-1   1/1     Running   0          49s
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-4p9l5                              1/1     Running   0          98s
kube-system   pod/kube-scheduler-kube-weave-master-1            1/1     Running   0          53s
kube-system   pod/weave-net-z6mhw                               2/2     Running   0          27s
```

Coredns pod description:

```
kubectl describe pod/coredns-576cbf47c7-6qbtq -n kube-system
Name:               coredns-576cbf47c7-6qbtq
Namespace:          kube-system
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               kube-weave-master-1/10.154.0.8
Start Time:         Fri, 05 Oct 2018 11:06:54 +0000
Labels:             k8s-app=kube-dns
                    pod-template-hash=576cbf47c7
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.32.0.3
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/coredns-576cbf47c7
Containers:
  coredns:
    Container ID:  docker://db1712600b4c927b99063fa41bc36c3346c55572bd63730fc993f03379fa457b
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.2.2
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/coredns@sha256:3e2be1cec87aca0b74b7668bbe8c02964a95a402e45ceb51b2252629d608d03a
    Ports:         53/UDP, 53/TCP, 9153/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/UDP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      -conf
      /etc/coredns/Corefile
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 05 Oct 2018 11:06:57 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      memory:  170Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     70Mi
    Liveness:     http-get http://:8080/health delay=60s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/coredns from config-volume (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from coredns-token-wp7tm (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      coredns
    Optional:  false
  coredns-token-wp7tm:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  coredns-token-wp7tm
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     CriticalAddonsOnly
                 node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                 From                          Message
  ----     ------            ----                ----                          -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  23m (x12 over 24m)  default-scheduler             0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.
  Normal   Scheduled         23m                 default-scheduler             Successfully assigned kube-system/coredns-576cbf47c7-6qbtq to kube-weave-master-1
  Normal   Pulled            23m                 kubelet, kube-weave-master-1  Container image "k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.2.2" already present on machine
  Normal   Created           23m                 kubelet, kube-weave-master-1  Created container
  Normal   Started           23m                 kubelet, kube-weave-master-1  Started container
```

Also, provide your `config.yaml` that is used by `kubeadm init --config config.yaml` to better understand your problem with specifying config file location.

Comment: I dumped the configuration from master but feeding the full configuration back in init caused an error so that's another problem. Anyway, I stripped the config to minimal and this is what is left (| for new line):
`apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha3|kind: InitConfiguration|---|apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1|kind: KubeletConfiguration|resolvConf: /path_to_my_config/resolv.conf`
However, kubeadm doesn't pick up the resolvConf variable and `--resolv-conf` flag in `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env` still points to `/etc/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to delete --network-plugin=cni in /var/lib/kubelet/kubeadmflags.env then restart the machine, the COredns will be running. Good luck